# How to select a column row wise in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I want to select the rows of the column `dr` individually which is selected by a counter variable `$i`. 
The code below isn't working . Where I'm doing the mistake ?

```
 update balance 
   set dr = 0 
 where
   dr = (select dr from balance order by gp_no asc limit 1 offset 0);
```

But getting the **ERROR :**

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'balance' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: So basically what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch a single row according to the value of a counter variable `$i` .
       `update balance set dr = 0 where dr = (select dr from balance order by gp_no asc limit 1 offset $i )`
I'm using it with php . The values to be updated for `dr` can be 0, `$debited_amount ` etc  .

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ??

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use a `join`:

```
update balance b join
       (select dr from balance order by gp_no asc limit 1 offset 0
       ) bb
       on b.dr = bb.dr
    set b.dr = 0;
```

Alternatively, if you just want to update one row, you can use `order by` and `limit` directly in the update:

```
update balance b
    set dr = 0
    order by gp_no asc
    limit 1;
```

However, this won't be exactly equivalent to your query, if `dr` is not unique.

Comment: What is b here in your second solution ?

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I execute your first solution 

`ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'dr' in field list is ambiguous`

Answer (score 0):

It is working now . Thanks @gordon :) . Since I was unable to edit your post , That's why I had to post it here ..

```
update balance b join
       (select dr from balance order by gp_no asc limit 1 offset 0
       ) bb
       on b.dr = bb.dr
    set b.dr = 0;
```